# Python synchronize pySerial item

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, pyserial

Iam using pySerial to communicate through the COM port. But now I need to work with 1 item of pySerial in 2 different threads. To be sure: I am opened port before threads started and I cant close it inside the Thread. So the question is how to use 1 serial port to write there from 2 different threads without closing? I am sure it has to be some synchro but how to do it in Python? 
Thanks